# Undefined index: page jqGrid

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, jqgrid

I'm new in jqGrid. I'm trying to get data from database in my grid but I got error Undefined index: page, Undefined index: rows, Undefined index: sidx, Undefined index: sord in my server.php file. I got grid on grid.html, but no data from database.

I have grid.html

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "server.php",
        datatype: "xml",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["Zaposleni ID", "Ime", "Prezime", "Godine staza", "Mesecna plata", "Godisnja plata", "Broj odradjenih projekata", "Kod zaposlenog", "Odeljenje"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "zap_id", width: 55 },
            { name: "ime", width: 90 },
            { name: "prezime", width: 90 },
            { name: "godine_staza", width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: "mesecna_plata", width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: "godisnja_plata", width: 80, align: "right" },
            { name: "broj_odradjenih_projekata", width: 50 },
            { name: "kod_zaposlenog", width: 50 },
            { name: "odeljenje", width: 150 }
        ],
        autowidth: true,
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "invid",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "Zaposleni"
    }); 
}); 
</script>
...
```

dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$database="kompanija";
?>
```

server.php

```
<?php 
//include the information needed for the connection to MySQL data base server. 
// we store here username, database and password 
include("dbconfig.php"); //

// to the url parameter are added 4 parameters as described in colModel
// we should get these parameters to construct the needed query
// Since we specify in the options of the grid that we will use a GET method 
// we should use the appropriate command to obtain the parameters. 
// In our case this is $_GET. If we specify that we want to use post 
// we should use $_POST. Maybe the better way is to use $_REQUEST, which
// contain both the GET and POST variables. For more information refer to php documentation.
// Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1. 
$page = $_GET['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 

// connect to the MySQL database server 
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error()); 

// select the database 
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error connecting to db."); 

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM zaposleni"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
              $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
              $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT zaposleni.zap_id, zaposleni.ime, zaposleni.prezime, zaposleni.godine_staza, zaposleni.mesecna_plata, zaposleni.godisnja_plata, zaposleni.broj_odradjenih_projekata, zaposleni.kod_zaposlenog, odeljenje.od_id FROM zaposleni INNER JOIN odeljenje ON zaposleni.od_id=odeljenje.od_id ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 

// we should set the appropriate header information. Do not forget this.
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .=  "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
$s .= "<records>".$count."</records>";

// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $s .= "<row id='". $row['zap_id']."'>";            
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['zap_id']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['ime']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['prezime']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['godine_staza']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['mesecna_plata']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['godisnja_plata']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['broj_odradjenih_projekata']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['kod_zaposlenog']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['od_id']."</cell>";
    $s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>"; 

echo $s;

?>
```

Can somebody help me please? I can't find issue.

Comment: Have you imported the required jquery libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sortname: "invid"**

you dont have such column in your grid colmodel.

sortname: "zap_id

And set up index for all columns, like this

```
{ name: "zap_id",index:"zap_id" , width: 55 }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me! I got data from my database, and that was the biggest problem. But I still got errors when open server.php, it's still the same Undefined index: page, rows... Why that?

Comment: Well, to make  server.php not getting any errors, when you trying to load it without ajax data from grid you need to set up default values for this 4 vars: $page = $_GET['page']:1; $limit = $_GET['rows']:100; $sidx = $_GET['sidx']:'zap_id'; $sord = $_GET['sord']:'asc';